# Google Script - Function - Not Defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-defined-functions, custom-function

I have the following script that is used to apportion each month as 1/12th of the year and find the difference between 2 dates. For example the function sums January to June as 50% of the year instead of 49% (181/365). I would like to move my excel s/s to Google but can't seem to get the function working in Google Script.

**Excel Script**

```
Function PartMonths(x, y)

PartMonths = (DateDiff("M", (DateSerial(Year(x), Month(x) + 1, 1) - 1), 
(DateSerial(Year(y), Month(y) + 1, 1) - 1) + 1) - 2 + Day(y) / 
Day(DateSerial(Year(y), Month(y) + 1, 1) - 1) + (Day(DateSerial(Year(x), 
Month(x) + 1, 1) - 1) - Day(x) + 1) / Day(DateSerial(Year(x), Month(x) + 1, 
1) - 1)) / 12

End Function
```

**Google Script**

```
function PartMonths(x, y) 

{ return PartMonths =(DateDif((Date(Year(x), Month(x) + 1, 1)), 
(Date(Year(y), Month(y) + 1, 1) - 1) + 1,"M") - 1 + Day(y) / 
 Day(Date(Year(y), Month(y) + 1, 1) - 1) + (Day(Date(Year(x), Month(x) + 1,
 1) - 1) - Day(x) + 1) / Day(Date(Year(x), Month(x) + 1, 1)-1))
 }
```

x and y are dates which are variable inputs. When debugging the code in Google Scripts it says 'ReferenceError: "DateDif" is not defined'

I'm not sure how to define it? Help!

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm new to this and haven't used Google Script much. I'll have a look at the websites you have recommended. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To define a function use

```
function DateDif(arg){
   //Add here what should DateDif do

   return something // something is the object reference to be returned by the function
                    // but you could use a literal like an integer, string or other 
                    // primitives

}
```

Reference

- [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript saves the date in milliseconds since 01/01/1970

```
// fd final date JavaScript object date
// fi Initial date  JavaScript object date
// Return date difference in fraction of day
function DateDif (fd,id){
  var dayms=24*3600*1000;
  return ( fd.valueof()-fi.valueof())/dayms;
}
```

However if you recover the value dates from gsheet or excel. It is enough wenn you return fd-fi as excel is coding in days what is after dot is fraction of day